# How to add multiple sprites of the same texture in a set pattern? Swift/SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

This is just a general question, but is there any way to populate the same sprite in a pattern?

For example, if you drew a shape, a circle, is there anyway you can get the sprites to outline that circle, where they would be slightly spaced apart?

I feel it would be easier to do this than programmatically set the location of each sprite around the circle.

Thank you

Comment: To answer both of your questions: yes.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D can you send me to a reference to help?